# Spring Data JPA Projection with select distinct

Tags: spring, jpa, projection

I have a database table which holds Metadata for documents. My task now is to get a list with documenttypes. The documenttypes are not unique in the database table but of course I want them to be in my list. The sql is very simple:

```
SELECT DISTINCT groupname, group_displayorder
FROM t_doc_metadata
ORDER BY group_displayorder;
```

I have learned that I can use projections to get a subset of fields from my entity DocMetadata. I solved this as follows. My Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_DOC_METADATA")
@Data
public class DocMetadata {
..............

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String displayname;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Integer displayorder;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String groupname;

    @Column(name="GROUP_DISPLAYORDER",
        nullable=false)
    private Integer groupDisplayorder;

    @Column(name="METADATA_CHANGED_TS",
        nullable=false,
        columnDefinition="char")
    private String metadataChangedTimestamp;
..........
}
```

My inteface for projection:

```
public interface GroupnameAndOrder {

    String getGroupname();
    Integer getGroupDisplayorder();
    void setGroupname(String name);
    void setGroupDisplayorder(int order);
}
```

Now I thought I'd be extraordinary clever by adding these lines to my repository:

```
@Query("select distinct d.groupname, d.groupDisplayorder from DocMetadata d order by d.groupDisplayorder")  
public List<GroupnameAndOrder> findSortedGroupnames();
```

Sadly, when iterating over the result list and calling *getGroupname()* the result is null.

So I changed the lines in my repository according to the documentation:

```
public List<GroupnameAndOrder> findBy();
```

Now I get the groupnames but of course they are not unique now. So it doesn't solve my problem.

Is there any way to receive a ordered list with unique groupnames?

Comment: How do we get unique result if annotated with custom query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to be too clever. Instead just write the proper find method and return the `GroupnameAndOrder`. Spring Data JPA will then only retrieve what is needed for the projection.

Something like this should do the trick.

```
List<GroupnameAndOrder> findDistinctByOrderByGroupDisplayorder();
```

Comment: That easy?!?! Thank you so much. I have to add a tiny correction if someone else runs into the same problem: the method name should be findDistinctByOrderByGroupDisplayorder(); the "By"between distinct and orderBy is essential because I don't use any params for ordering.

Comment: You're right, typed it to quickly... Modified the answer.

Comment: sadly this doesn't solve the issue with select distinct inside a @Query when auto-generated find method is not possible

Comment: looks like this issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1679